# Ring $\mathbb F_q[x]/\langle f^n \rangle $ where f is irreducible

Tags: ring-theory

We know that the ring  $\mathbb F_q[x]/\langle f \rangle $ is a Galois ring when $f$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb F_q$.

Is there any idea to describe the ring  $\mathbb F_q[x]/\langle f^n \rangle $ where $n$ is a natural number and $f$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb F_q$?

Comment: You can prove (by induction on $n$) that there is an element of the form $y=x+fg$ in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ so that $f(y)=0$ in this ring. Note that $n=y-x$ is nilpotent in this ring. This is a special case of the Jordan decomposition. It also follows that the ring *contains* $\mathbb{F}_q[y]/(f(y))$. This should give you a structure theorem.

Comment: In addition to Kapil's comment, please also try this out with something simple like $\mathbb F_q[x]/(x^2)$ to get an idea of the pattern.